# Do the tridevi (Saraswati,Lakshmi,Parvati) play any role in the Mahabharata?

Tags: mahabharata, lakshmi, parvati, saraswati

Sita as Lakshmi's avatara, plays a primary role in Ramayana.

The three Moola female deities don't seem to participate actively as their spouses do in the epic and there are conflicting theories as to who incarnated as Draupadi.